# why is -ldgcc option not working in my make file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, operating-system, debian

im trying to complie some operating system example code and when i run make (in running the default debian eviroment on a chromebook lunix termial) it gives me the folowing error:

```
kuzai_longmane@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/removable/32GB/Operating systems (source code)/my_cool_os/my_cool_os$ make
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -lgcc start.o libc/string/memcmp.o libc/string/memset.o libc/string/strcat.o libc/string/strchr.o libc/string/strcmp.o libc/string/strcpy.o libc/string/strlen.o libc/string/strncmp.o libc/string/strstr.o libc/string/strutil.o libc/string/ctos.o kernel/tty.o kernel/io.o kernel.o -T linker.ld -o myos
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:28: myos] Error 1
```

any sugestions or things i overlooked?

Comment: -m32 tells to generate code for 32bit but NO libgcc32 was found. It little unusual to explicity link with libgcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to generate and link 32-bit code (the `-m32` option), but the linker can't find a 32-bit version of libgcc.  The message says its *is* finding a 64-bit version, so the problem is probably just that you don't have 32-bit libs installed.  I think on debian, you need to install the ia32-libs package for that.

Comment: how would i do that? is it like an ¨apt-get" or a git repo?

Comment: If you're using apt as your package manager, yes, you just use apt-get.  If you're using a different package manager, you would use that.